# changing biblatex style for each printbibliography

Tags: biblatex

I am using 3 `\printbibliography` commands (each selecting a subset of citations). For two of these I would like to set `doi`, `url` and `eprint` to `false`. If I would want to do this globally, I would do this at the package import, giving these as option, but I couldn't find a way to do this for a single `\printbibliography`. Is this possible, and if yes, how?

**MWEB**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true,sorting=none,backend=biber,maxnames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Perunov,
author = {Perunov, Nikolay and Marsland, Robert A and England, Jeremy L},
doi = {10.1103/PhysRevX.6.021036},
keywords = {Biological Physics,Complex Systems,Statistical Physics,Subject Areas},
mendeley-groups = {dissertation},
title = {{Statistical Physics of Adaptation}},
url = {https://journals.aps.org/prx/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevX.6.021036}
}

@article{Strombom2011,
author = {Str{\"{o}}mbom, Daniel},
doi = {10.1016/j.jtbi.2011.05.019},
journal = {Journal of Theoretical Biology},
mendeley-groups = {dissertation},
month = {aug},
number = {1},
pages = {145--151},
title = {{Collective motion from local attraction}},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S002251931100261X},
volume = {283},
year = {2011},
keywords = "nourl"
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[title={please no url},heading=subbibliography,keyword=nourl]

\printbibliography[title={please url},heading=subbibliography,notkeyword=nourl]
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: sure, see above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To temporarily disable doi, url etc. you can use

```
\settoggle{bbx:url}{false}
\settoggle{bbx:doi}{false}
\settoggle{bbx:eprint}{false}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true,sorting=none,backend=biber,maxnames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Perunov,
author = {Perunov, Nikolay and Marsland, Robert A and England, Jeremy L},
doi = {10.1103/PhysRevX.6.021036},
keywords = {Biological Physics,Complex Systems,Statistical Physics,Subject Areas},
mendeley-groups = {dissertation},
title = {{Statistical Physics of Adaptation}},
url = {https://journals.aps.org/prx/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevX.6.021036}
}

@article{Strombom2011,
author = {Str{\"{o}}mbom, Daniel},
doi = {10.1016/j.jtbi.2011.05.019},
journal = {Journal of Theoretical Biology},
mendeley-groups = {dissertation},
month = {aug},
number = {1},
pages = {145--151},
title = {{Collective motion from local attraction}},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S002251931100261X},
volume = {283},
year = {2011},
keywords = "nourl"
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

{
    \settoggle{bbx:url}{false}
    \settoggle{bbx:doi}{false}
    \settoggle{bbx:eprint}{false}
    \printbibliography[title={please no url},heading=subbibliography,keyword=nourl]
}

\printbibliography[title={please url},heading=subbibliography,notkeyword=nourl]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As an afterthought: I tried to be smart and applied your schema to issn (`\settoggle{bbx:issn}{false}`), but it complained about not knowing what to do about it. Where can I find the docs for these settings? There are actually several other totally unimportant properties that some journals export when you save bibtex citations (e.g. I just noticed I have language too) and would suppress them.

Comment: @fbence To look up what `toggle`s exist, have a look into `standard.bbx` (the list is short: `\newtoggle{bbx:isbn}
\newtoggle{bbx:url}
\newtoggle{bbx:doi}
\newtoggle{bbx:eprint}
\newtoggle{bbx:related}`)  To remove things like language I would use `\AtEveryBibitem{
 \clearlist{language}}`

Comment: One could also use `\AtNextBibliography` in combination with `\AtEveryBibitem` to have a finer control over only the next bibliography.